# Variadic Template + static array

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Here we go, I got a template class with variadic classes arguments, each class has its own id from an enum value, for example:

```
struct A
    {
        enum ETypeID
        { 
            Value = 244
        };
    };
```

(same pattern for some other classes)

now I got :

```
template<typename TypeList...>
struct TClass
{
    static int _IDs[sizeof(TypeList)...];
};
```

I can't figure out how to feed the static array with each `ETypeID::Value` from the given typelist.

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename... TypeList>
struct TClass
{
    constexpr static int _IDs[sizeof...(TypeList)] = {TypeList::Value...};
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6jKDkgDNwMogmxqb)

---

- `constexpr` is required for in-place `static` data member initialization
- `sizeof...(TypeList)` evaluates to the number of elements in the `TypeList...` pack
- For `TypeList = {A, B, C}`, `TypeList::Value...` expands to: `A::Value, B::Value, C::Value`